# Google Spreadsheet api returning only 500 results

Tags: google-sheets-api

While querying https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full?v=3.0 i'm only ever able to get 500 results back. I have tried passing start-index and max-results but still my list is truncated to 500. How can i get all my spreadsheets?

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full?start-index=1&max-results=1000

I've also tried max-results of 100 and using the "link rel='next'" to page, but still hitting a hard stop at 500. Is this a limit?